# Using LoopBack as an API proxy with response restructuring

Tags: javascript, rest, loopbackjs

I have to access data from a non-RESTful API and am attempting to build a new web service that accesses the original API and re-exposes it as a RESTful API.

I'd like to use [LoopBack](http://loopback.io) to achieve this.

So far I have:

```
var loopback = require("loopback");

var ds = loopback.createDataSource({
  connector: require("loopback-connector-rest"),
  debug: false,
  operations: [
    {
        "template": {
        "method": "POST",
        "url": "http://192.168.1.20/OLD_API/Web_SVC.ASMX/CALLFUNC",
        "headers": {
          "accepts": "application/json",
          "content-type": "application/json"
        },
        "body": "{body}"
      },
      "functions": {
        "create": ["body"]
      }
    }
  ]});

var model = ds.createModel('debtor');

model.create({ "DLLNAME":"WEB_DLLS.GET_AGED", "FUNCTIONNAME":"M_GET_AGED", "PARAMETERNAME":"1234" },function (err, result, response) {
    console.log(JSON.parse(result.d));
});
```

Ideally I would like to expose this `POST` as a `GET` at `/api/debtors/{clientId}` where `clientId` is the `PARAMETERNAME` in the `model.create` call.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can further parameterize the body for operation mapping as follows:

   body: {
   "DLLNAME":"WEB_DLLS.GET_AGED", 
   "FUNCTIONNAME":"M_GET_AGED", 
   "PARAMETERNAME":"{parameterName}" 
   }
2. You either change the create remoting metadata or wrap the create to another method and expose it over GET.

   model.createOverGet = function(param, cb) {
     this.create(..., cb);
   }

See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Remote+methods+and+hooks#Remotemethodsandhooks-Definingremotemethods.

Comment: Does the `model.createOverGet` refer to changing "the create remoting metadata"? Can I do this in the `datasources.json` file? If not, how do I correctly expose the model over REST? Also, is there a way to parse the response from the the original API before exposing it again?